# Returning the first positive number in a list using what I already have (if possible)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some python practice functions I am trying to figure out and I am having trouble with the following function:

```
def find_positive(lst):
 '''(lst) -> num
 Return the index of the first occurrence of a positive number in 
 the list of numbers lst. Return None if the list does not 
 have any positive numbers
 >>>find_positive([-10, -4, -2, 8, 3, 5, -4])
 8
 >>>find_positive([-2, -4, -9, 0])
 None
 >>>find_positive([5, 3, 9])
 5
 '''
```

I thought perhaps I could make a new list with only the positive numbers then return the first number in that list (ie. index 0). I can do this with the following:

```
  newL = lst[:]
for item in lst:
    if item <= 0:
        newL.remove(item)
return newL[0]
```

However, this would not (and does not) return 'None' when I use an example without positive numbers such as the second doc string example. It returns an error when I use a list without any positive number. Is there an easy way I can modify my existing function to have it return 'None' or is the way I approached the function an impossible way to have it able to return 'None'? If I need to rethink, is there an easy way to use some kind of 'if item <=0' statement and/or indexes to return the first positive number? Thanks!!

Comment: The problem says that it should return the index of the first positive number, rather than the number itself.  Are you sure you're solving the correct problem?  For `[-5, -3, 6, 4]` it should return `2`.

Comment: Why aren't you answering Tom's question?

Comment: Thank you so much I didn't even realize that. Luckily people commented on solving both so now I'll know how to do either. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Don't know why you're making it so complicated.

```
def find_positive(lst):
    for x in lst:
         if x > 0:
             return x
```

Answer (score 1):

I will comment it so you can understand it:

```
def find_positive(lst):
    for index, item in enumerate(lst): # Loop that tracks index and item value
        if item > 0: # If the item is bigger than 0...
            return index # Return the index of that item
    return None # Returns None otherwise
```

The instructions are a bit unclear as if you need to return the index or the value of the first positive item. If you want to return the value instead and not the index, then you should change the `found = index` and set it to `found = item`. Here is the documentation for [Enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#enumerate) and how it works.

**Update after comments**:
This is an example of how returning None could be useful.

```
my_variable_name = find_positive([-4, -2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]) # Call the function
if my_variable_name is None: # Check if None was returned
    print("hey, no positives found")
else:
    print("I found {} as first positive".format(my_variable_name))
```

Before you ask, `{}` is a placeholder to format strings. That way we can build more readable strings than if you insert code in the middle of a string.

Comment: And you're returning the index of the last negative number.  Try again.

Comment: Positive numbers are greater than zero.  You should also be returning the index as soon as you see it.  As is, you're returning the index of the last negative number

Comment: No need for break, `if item > 0: return index`

Comment: Hm, yes @Reti43, the code could be improved that way. Will update it.

Comment: Thanks Saelyth and everyone else! I haven't learned enumerate in class but I will look read about it at link you provided and will hopefully be able to figure it out. What does None do? I thought it was supposed to return the string None but I realized its not since its not in string quotes in the doc string - does it just return nothing?

Comment: I'm glad you learnt something new. None is a constant that represent the absence of a value. So yeah, in effect it returns nothing at all, but its get tracked so you can code something in case nothing is returned: I will update my answer and I hope that clarifies your questions. Please remember to accept a correct answer and upvote using the controls at the left side of each answer.